# Writing to file in a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, fs

The function here creates a bunch of files but does not write to them. How ever, if I remove the `Promise.all` in the end and don't resolve the function at all it DOES write the data to the files. It doesn't matter what I try to write, I can comment out everything and just write 'hello world' and it still won't write anything. The question is simple, why?

```
const writeSmilFiles = (smilInfo) => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    const p1 = smilPartOne();
    const p2 = smilPartTwo();

    let promises = dataTypes.new.camera_set.map(instance => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const smilEntries = smilInfo.filter(smil => smil.BroadcastAndKlippTupleId == instance.BroadcastAndKlippTupleId && smil.CameraId == instance.CameraId);
        try {
          const fileName = `${__dirname}/newSmilFiles/${smilEntries[0].Smil}`;
          const file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
          file.write(p1);

          smilEntries.forEach(entry => {
            const smilEntry = smilSwitch(entry.Filename, entry.Bitrate, entry.Width, entry.Height);
            file.write(smilEntry);
            console.log(smilEntry);
            file.write('\n');
        });

          file.write(p2);
          file.end();
          resolve(`Smil written.`);
        } catch (ex) {
          reject(ex);
        }
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(msg => {
      resolve(msg);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Would you provide the simplified "hello world" version in your question as well please? It might be easier to debug that simplified version.

Comment: This is not the cause of your issue, but you should use `return Promise.all(...)` and NOT wrap it in an extra promise you are creating yourself.  What you are doing is a promise anti-pattern and, indeed, cases programming errors if any of your promises reject.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks so much, great tip. I've been wondering about this actually - makes sense now! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolve when the stream has actually finished:

```
file.on("finish", () => resolve(`Smil written.`));
```

Comment: Still funcionalities to learn in the fs library I guess. Thanks a bunch :)